# How do I connect a to a mysql database hosted on pythonanywhere?

Tags: mysql, pythonanywhere

I have bought a basic 6$ `pythonanywhere` server which allows for `SCP` and `SSH` connections to their servers. I have deployed my `flask` application (`REST API`) to the server and set up a local environment (installed packages, set up path and environmental variables). I ran the app, and it gives me the `404 page` on the `/` route which is actually a sign that it is working.

However when I try to hit a route like `/api/users/3` for example, it gives me an `error 500` (internal server error). I dug around some `log` files on the server and found one which is basically the output of the `WSGI` web server which is host to my flask application. It said that there is an issue with the database communication. From what I understand, it connected successfully but it couldn't query the data from the table:

```
 (1044, "Access denied for user 'secret_username'@'%' to database 'test'")
```

I have tried to fix this through the web mysql console by giving my `<secret_username>@secret_username.pythonanywhere.com` all the privilages to `test.*`, but it gives me an `access error` once again. I tried to SSH into the machine that is host to the mysql server and tried to connect to it - `secret_username.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com` but it doesn't allow me to ssh into this server.

Has anyone experienced this issue? I am almost sure that my connection is set up correctly because if it didn't establish connection it would give me an access error with message `using password "yes". I've read on forums a bit, they suggest installing a mysql server on the same server as the flask application, but I don't have access to sude for some reason, probably due to my cheap plan. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the MySQL database provided by PythonAnywhere, with the hostname `secret_username.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com`, then your database will be called `secret_username$test`, not just `test` -- see the "Databases" page on the PythonAnywhere website.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will try that out and let you know if it solves my issue.